# SQL Update not actually updating? Done

Tags: c#, sql

SOLVED: I figured out my own issue. It was working as I thought. I just was not reading the correct row.

I am trying to update a few columns in a row, in the Table [Profiles]. I don't get any errors when running this code but it doesn't actually update the columns. I have never used an update before. What am I doing wrong.

```
string currentPage = Request.Url.ToString();
Uri myUri = new Uri(currentPage);
string position = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("position");
string electionYear = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("year");
var finalkey = Session["Userid"].ToString() + "^" + position + "^" + electionYear;
string sqlquery = "UPDATE [Profiles] SET Qualifications=@Qualifications, Platform=@Platform, FamilyLife=@FamilyLife, Website=@Website where FinalKey=@FinalKey";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbLocation);
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
try
{
conn.Open();
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinalKey", finalkey);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qualifications", qualificationsBox.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Platform", platformBox.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FamilyLife", familyBox.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Website", candWebsiteBox.Text);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch { }
conn.Close()
```

Comment: Why the `catch{}`? Don't you want to know what's wrong if something happens? This is probably your problem: something's wrong, but you're ignoring it!

Comment: Is your FinalKey really in that format?  Assuming so, put a breakpoint and step through it.  The Update query looks right though.  Perhaps getting caught in the catch and not throwing anything.

Comment: how do you know if it's not generating an error when you have nothing in the catch{} you are not even trapping an Exception ex for example

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thats just the thing, I have a messagebox that displays if it was successful or not and it always come back successful. So having something in the Catch{} doesn't help.

Comment: No, no, no. Remove the try/catch entirely. Or at worst, do `catch (Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());}` Otherwise, you will never know what went wrong.

Comment: I hope you still got rid of that try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the value of **finalkey** by set break Point ! Only Possible for Not Updating  is,

There is no matching record found with this **finalkey** value.

another option

set where class value manually Like where finalvalue="user1dec" and check if it is work, then u can........

**var finalkey = Session["Userid"].ToString() + "^" + position + "^" + electionYear;**

Comment: The question was marked -1, that means it is no up to the site's stadards. It is possible that it can't be answered. And please try to write correct English, many readers here aren't native speakers. Thanks!